Putting an object in front of another one (and covering the whole other object)
I have two SVG files, they are a transparent outlined oval and a colored oval without an outline. I want to cover the colored oval completely with the transparent outlined oval, but it keeps on not aligning with the sides of the oval. Here's my CSS code and the result:
.character {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; /* Adjust the size as needed */
    height: 400px; /* Adjust the size as needed */
}

.part {
    position: absolute;
}

.head {
    animation: float 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.headcolor {
   z-index: 1;
   margin-top: -200px;
   position: relative; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}

.headoutline {
   z-index: 2;
   position: relative;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}

@keyframes float {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0); /* Starting position */
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-5px); /* Float up by 10 pixels */
    }
}


Upon changing the margin-top of .headcolor to -500px, nothing changes:

And here is what my result is supposed to look like, my two svg files, and my HTML code.

https://svgshare.com/i/1Aqg.svg
https://svgshare.com/i/1ArY.svg
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Character Assembly</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="character">
        <!-- Outline SVG -->
        <div class="head">
        <object data="/svgs/head/shapes/9.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="headoutline"></object>
        <!-- Filling SVG -->
        <object data="/svgs/head/shapes/7.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="headcolor"></object>
    </div>
      <!--  <object data="body.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>
        <object data="leftarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="rightarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="leftlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>
        <object data="rightlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>
    </div> -->

    <script src="player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

UPDATE 9/26: I edited this part of the CSS:
.headoutline {
   z-index: 2;
   position: relative; margin
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}

And now the svgs are closer. But the outline still won't cover the whole colored oval...


Please provide the SVG images as well, otherwise this is hard to reproduce. If you can't host them somewhere externally, so that we can all see them, then you can use a service like https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ to convert them into Data URIs.

@c3roe edited the post.

Instead of using <object> for each SVG you can use the <image> element inside a SVG element.
Here, I included the two SVG as data URIs, but this can of course be replaced by a URL to the right SVG.


.head {
    animation: float 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes float {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0); /* Starting position */
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-5px); /* Float up by 10 pixels */
    }
}
<div class="head">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="90">
    <image href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />
    <image href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"/>
  </svg>
</div>




I already have the URL pathnames to the svgs, am I supposed to use img src=that url?

@user27361334 You should use the path to your owne SVG files. The data URIs in the example are just for showing that it works with the limitations of StackOverflow.

Why don't you create it with css?
Here's an example:


.oval {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: wheat;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
<div class="oval"></div> 



